# Destructor of a joinable std::thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11, g++

The specification (? - got it from cppreference) states:

> ~thread(); (since C++11)
>
> Destroys the thread object. If *this still has an associated running thread 
>           (i.e.   joinable() == true), std::terminate() is called.

I've checked that calling `std::terminate()` inside thread aborts the whole program.

So to check destructor behaviour I wrote this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> thread_ptr(new std::thread([](){
            std::cout << "Starting thread: " << std::endl;
            while(1) {}
            }));
    while(!thread_ptr->joinable()){}
    std::cout << thread_ptr->joinable() << std::endl;
    thread_ptr.release();
    std::cout << "Main is still alive!" << std::endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Expecting abort of whole process.

No such thing happened, all output was a permutation of messages, like:

> 1Starting thread:
>
> Main is still alive!

I'm using g++ : Thread model: posix, gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04)

Do I have wrong understanding of specification? Wrong code? Or g++ isn't just compliant with this specification?

Comment: `while(1) {}` is UB BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant `thread_ptr.reset()` instead of `thread_ptr.release()`. `release()` relinquishes ownership of the pointer, i.e. you leak the `std::thread` instance and its destructor is thus never called.

Comment: Well spotted.  With that change, the entire program aborts (at least with Clang).